# Add a new subnode as first sibling in xmlstarlet

Tags: xml, siblings, xmlstarlet

I want to insert a subnode as the first subnode sibling using xmlstarlet. I have the following xml file:
src.xml

```
<xml>
   <subnode> Peter Paul </subnode>
   <subnode> Peter daniel </subnode>
   <subnode> Peter Peter </subnode>
</xml>
```

I would like whenever I do insert a new sibling, it will appear as first sibling not as last sibling:

```
xmlstarlet ed -s -L "//xml/[1]" -t elem -n subnode -v "Mary James" src.xml
```

It will look like this:

```
<?xml version =1.0"?>
<xml>
   <subnode> Mary James </subnode>
   <subnode> Peter Paul </subnode>
   <subnode> Peter daniel </subnode>
   <subnode> Peter Peter </subnode>
</xml>
```

I have tried  options i, a . I need help.

Answer (score 0):

##### With `-i` aka `insert`:

```
$ xmlstarlet ed -L -i "//xml//subnode[1]" \
      -t elem -n subnode \
      -v " Mary James " \
      file.xml
```

##### `cat file.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml>
  <subnode> Mary James </subnode>
  <subnode> Peter Paul </subnode>
  <subnode> Peter daniel </subnode>
  <subnode> Peter Peter </subnode>
</xml>
```